# VBA User Defined Chart Function Creating Multiple Series

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have a VBA spreadsheet that allows a user to add the contents of another spreadsheet, format it, calculate totals, and add a pie chart. It is mostly working fine except there is one month tab that is creating a series per data point when we want all data points in one pie.

Here is the function to create the pie chart.

```
Sub AddChart(CurrentWorkSheet As Worksheet)
Dim FirstRow As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim FirstColumn As String
Dim LastColumn As String
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim i As Integer

FirstRow = RowCount(CurrentWorkSheet) + 2
LastRow = FirstRow + 4
Set DataRange = CurrentWorkSheet.Range("I" & FirstRow & ":I" & LastRow)

Dim MyChart As Chart
Set MyChart = CurrentWorkSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlPie).Chart

MyChart.SetSourceData Source:=DataRange
MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True

For i = 1 To MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
    If i = 1 Then
        MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    ElseIf i = 2 Then
        MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ElseIf i = 3 Then
        MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160)
    ElseIf i = 4 Then
        MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).DataLabel.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ElseIf i = 5 Then
        MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
    Else
    End If
Next

MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = CurrentWorkSheet.Range("H" & CStr(FirstRow) & ":H" & CStr(LastRow))
End Sub
```

In this workbook there is a `YTD` worksheet and a worksheet for each month. When it gets to April the pie has one color. All of the other months are fine.

The data set is as follows:

```
ATTACHMENT            962.31
DAMAGE              3,279.94
MODIFICATIONS         451.00
REPAIRS             5,239.78
TIRES               1,979.04
```

The data range is rows 51-55.

```
=SERIES(,'Apr 2014'!$H$51:$H$55,'Apr 2014'!$I$51,1)
```

When I look at the series in Excel there are 5 listed, the first is `ATTACHMENT` and the last 4 are `1`. Each month is using the same function as well as the `YTD` tab and they are all OK except April.

Any ideas what could be causing it?

Comment: I'd guess there's something different about the layout, but you may simply need to add the PlotBy argument `MyChart.SetSourceData Source:=DataRange, PlotBy:=xlColumns` or use `xlRows` if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I changed the following

```
Set DataRange = CurrentWorkSheet.Range("I" & FirstRow & ":I" & LastRow)
```

to

```
Set DataRange = CurrentWorkSheet.Range("I" & CStr(FirstRow) & ":I" & CStr(LastRow))
```

Seems to be working now. Unsure why it worked OK on the other tabs....